# nginx/wsgi/Virtualenv/pip/yolk/django configuration add new module

Tags: django, nginx, wsgi, virtualenv, pip

I'm having a small problem with my setup.  I'm quite new to the Django world so bear with me.

A friend who is familiar has set up a VPS (Ubuntu) for my project.

I'm now on my own trying to add a new module (south) so I can use `manage.py migrate`

When the virtualenv was deactivated I installed the module

```
$ sudo pip -E /var/www/env/example.com install south
$ touch /var/www/sites/example.com.wsgi
$ source /var/www/env/example.com/bin/activate
```

It appeared to go fine

```
$ yolk -l
```

I see the south module.

at which point I run on my site

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
$ python manage.py migrate
```

I get this error though:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
Unknown command: 'migrate'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

I don't have a full understanding of what I'm doing but I'm willing to learn.

Maybe someone could point me in the right direction? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to add "south" to your INSTALLED_APPS list in your project's settings module. Django doesn't use south just because it is installed in the PYTHONPATH :-)

This has nothing to do with the rest of your server setup but just how you configure Django itself.

Comment: of course!  man i'm so stupid! sorry i should have known that.  Brain fart!